# Do I have to use ServerMode for Microsoft ReportViewer in a WebForm?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportmanager

I'm trying to view a `Hello world` report using Microsoft Reporting Services in a web application.

The reports I'll be creating are always refreshed when viewed (ie. no saved data) so I see no reason to use the Report Manager.

I want to include the `rdlc` file's in my web application itself where I'll have an `aspx` page that hosts the `ReportViewer`.

I've tried this hoping that `Local` could also mean local to the web app...

```
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "~/Reporting/Hello World.rdlc";
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

But that doesn't seem to be the case. I get the following error when I view my page.

> An error occurred during local report processing.The report definition
>   for report 'D:[local path to my web application
>   source]\~/Reporting/Hello World.rdlc' has not been specified Could not
>   find a part of the path'D:[local path to my web application
>   source]\~\Reporting\Hello World.rdlc'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Local Processing Mode means that the RDLC file is located as a local source, and not generated by the SQL Server.

From the error message, it looks like you have your slashes inverted.  Try playing around with the path, or more specifically, try changing the orientation of your slashes from / to \

It should work.